# How to install a RESTful WCF Webservice (.svc) on Mono?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, mono

How can i install a WCF webservice on a xsp server (linux)?

Is there a small tutorial or something?

The webservice ist RESTful.

Out of the Visual Studio IDE the service runs and a call to `http://localhost:63500/Service1.svc/GetData/test` gets the right result.

On the webserver there comes a asp like error message when calling the root path (`http://testserver:8084/`)

```
Argument is out of range. Parameter name: startIndex

Description: HTTP 400. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: startIndex
  at System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest.AssertFileAccessible () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest.ProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

With the "correct" path (`http://testserver:8084/Service1.svc/GetData/test`) the server returns nothing.

Maybe its just a configuration error?

Thank you!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Change to 80 default port may help you get rid of this issue. Use `http://testserver/Service1.svc/GetData/test` to visit it.